# What is C#'s most effective counterpart to Delphi's TStringList?

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi, list, object

In our Delphi application, we use a TStringList to store strings and corresponding objects.  For another project, I need to do something similar to this in C#, but am not sure what the most effective way of doing this is.  So far I've thought of using an array list, a list, or a dictionary.  Would one of these be effective at what I want to do?  If not, which is a good way to go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends what features of TStringList you need. There's not really a direct replacement.

A `dictionary<string,object>` is unordered, and you cannot have duplicate strings. There's no Text property to set all strings at once, etc. If all that is OK with you, I'd go for that.

Otherwise, you might consider defining a little class like:

```
public class Item { 
  public string String {get;set;} 
  public object Object {get;set;}
}
```

and then use `List<Item>`. That gives you an ordered list of (string,object) tuples.

Comment: `TStringList` is a [collection of strings](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstrings.html), isn't it?

Comment: @abatishchev yes, but it's more that that too - each string can be associated with an object, and the strings can be accessed as one big string (split by carriage return or other character).

Comment: Was leaning toward a dictionary, but forgot that it doesn't allow duplicates, so will use the list<item>.

Comment: @Tom: Check out `Enumerable<T>.TooLookup()` which is a dictionary allowing duplicates

Answer (score 3):

If the strings are unique, go with the `Dictionary<string, T>`. If they are not guaranteed to be unique, a dictionary will not be appropriate and you would want to maybe use a list of `Tuple<string, T>` (C# 4) or perhaps a list of `KeyValuePair<string, T>`, which would be very similar to a dictionary except obviously not guaranteeing uniqueness, and it preserves order where a dictionary would not necessarily do so.

```
Dictionary<string, T>> yourDictionary; // or
List<Tuple<string, T>> yourCollection; // or
List<KeyValuePair<string, T>> yourCollection;
```

Finally, you can define your own encapsulating type and create a list of *that* if you do not wish to use one of the other solutions.

Comment: `TStringList` is a [collection of strings](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstrings.html), isn't it?

Comment: @abatishchev, the key from the question is storing *strings and corresponding objects.*

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the features you need for your collection. I would use `Dictionary<string, object>` (generics).

Comment: `TStringList` is a [collection of strings](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/classes/tstrings.html), isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For a small list of objects I would use `Dictionary<string,xxx>` where `xxx` is the type of object you want to store indexed by string.

Comment: Dictionary is a hashtable with type safety

Comment: `Dictionary<K,V>` is generic Hashtable so there is no need to use HT

Answer (score 0):

this blog post show the differences between SortedList and Dictionary quite good

http://blog.bodurov.com/Performance-SortedList-SortedDictionary-Dictionary-Hashtable/

Answer (score 0):

Generic version:

```
List<string>
```

Direct, non-generic (don't use!):

```
ArrayList
```

See MSDN: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx)

Comment: I think he's more looking for a dictionary than a list

Comment: @vc: Yes if he don't want "counterpart to Delphi's TStringList" :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing!
believe me, my friend, because of the word "counterpart" I have to say Nothing!